# Multiple colors for Vuetify v-timeline center line

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, timeline

I need to change the color of the center line in the [v-timeline](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/timelines/) components of the Vuetify framework so that it will be a particular color up-to a certain colored dot and another color afterwards as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srlCY.png), is it possible to do so?

The color for the whole line could be changed as follows

```
.theme--light.v-timeline:before {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think only one way is setting linear-gradient. Because v-timeline divider setting up all the space. Try setting

```
background: linear-gradient(180deg, black 0% 50%, gray 50% 100%) !important
```